# left and right coset verifications

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

How to find the left and right cosets of the subgroup $H = \{r_0, s_0\}$ of $D_4$? And are they the same?

If we let $H' = \{r_0,r_2\}$, are the left and right cosets the same, where $H'$ is a subgroup of $D_4$?

Thanks

Comment: $D_4$ is a small group, and $H$ and $H'$ are *very* small; have you tried simply writing out the cosets? The right coset of $H$ by $r_2$, for instance, is $Hr_2=\{r_0r_2,s_0r_2\}$; $r_0r_2=r_2$, and $s_0r_2=$ what? Now do this for each of the $8$ elements of $D_4$, and do the same thing on the lefthand side, and compare the two collections of cosets.

Comment: Is s0r2 = s2, but why?

Comment: The left cosets of H by r2, is r2H = {r2r0,r2s0} and r2r0 = r2 and r2s0 = s2.

Comment: I can’t be sure, because it depends on how you’re labelling the elements of the group, but it seems likely. You need to write out the group multiplication table, so that you can simply look up each possible product; it’s only $8\times 8$.

Comment: Can you help out with the element s0 of H, for D4?

Comment: To make sure that my answer is correct, when I work it out? Thanks

Comment: I really can’t without knowing exactly how you’re labelling the elements. I’m reasonably sure that you’re using $r_0,r_1,r_2$ and $r_3$ for the rotations through $0°,90°,180°$, and $270°$ and the $s_i$ for the reflections, but I don’t know which reflection is which $s_i$, and in a product $xy$ I don’t know whether you’re thinking of doing $x$ first and then $y$, or the reverse.

Answer (score 2):

By actual computation using the multiplication table at the link that you gave, we have $$\begin{align*}
&Hr_0=\{r_0,s_0\}\text{ and }r_0H=\{r_0,s_0\}\\
&Hr_1=\{r_1,s_3\}\text{ and }r_1H=\{r_1,s_1\}\\
&Hr_2=\{r_2,s_2\}\text{ and }r_2H=\{r_2,s_2\}\\
&Hr_3=\{r_3,s_1\}\text{ and }r_3H=\{r_3,s_3\}\\
&Hs_0=\{s_0,r_0\}\text{ and }s_0H=\{s_0,r_0\}\\
&Hs_1=\{s_1,r_3\}\text{ and }s_1H=\{s_1,r_1\}\\
&Hs_2=\{s_2,r_2\}\text{ and }s_2H=\{s_2,r_2\}\\
&Hs_3=\{s_3,r_1\}\text{ and }s_3H=\{s_3,r_3\}\;.
\end{align*}$$

If you go carefully through both columns, you’ll see that each left coset and each right coset appears twice. The right cosets are

$$\begin{align*}
&Hr_0=\{r_0,s_0\}=\{s_0,r_0\}=Hs_0\\
&Hr_1=\{r_1,s_3\}=\{s_3,r_1\}=Hs_3\\
&Hr_2=\{r_2,s_2\}=\{s_2,r_2\}=Hs_2\\
&Hr_3=\{r_3,s_1\}=\{s_1,r_3\}=Hs_1\;,
\end{align*}$$

and the left cosets are

$$\begin{align*}
&r_0H=\{r_0,s_0\}=\{s_0,r_0\}=s_0H\\
&r_1H=\{r_1,s_1\}=\{s_1,r_1\}=s_1H\\
&r_2H=\{r_2,s_2\}=\{s_2,r_2\}=s_2H\\
&r_3H=\{r_3,s_3\}=\{s_3,r_3\}=s_3H\;.
\end{align*}$$

As you can see, the left and right cosets of $H$ are **not** all the same: $Hr_1=Hs_3$ and $Hr_3=Hs_1$ are right cosets that are not left cosets, and $r_1H=s_1H$ and $r_3H=s_3H$ are left cosets that are not right cosets.

I’ll leave $H'$ for you to try on your own, at least for now.

Comment: I'm stuck with H' and I'm not seeing what is being multiplied, like for example, s2H = ?

Comment: never mind, now getting it! thanks!